# Mysqli select and count by

Tags: php, mysqli, count

i have the following code. When i run into phpmyadmin the result returns correctly 9 rows of users and a column called |count(*) with the count next to each user. Whats wrong on my while and cant return me the count? It returns just the user when in php code

```
<?php
  if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT n.user, count(*) AS count_user FROM metadata n group by n.user")) {


                /* fetch associative array */
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                    printf ($row['user'], $row[count]);

                }

}

/* free result set */



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

hi if i understand correctly your Question try this :

```
<?php
 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "test");


if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  printf("Échec de la connexion : %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
  exit();
}

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT name FROM users ORDER BY name")) {

 /* get num rows */
 $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    printf($row['name']);
 }

 printf('Nombre of line %s',$row_cnt);

 $result->close();
}


$mysqli->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used wrong index. you gave alias `count_user` in your query so you must use it when you fetch.

Just change this

```
   printf ($row['user'], $row[count]);
```

to

```
   printf ($row['user'], $row['count_user']);
```